# Ubuntu not forwarding traffic between interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, routing, iptables

after searching for a good 9 hours on this, i figured asking this here might help.
I'm trying an Ubuntu machine as a router so i can introduce latency & etc. to test SD-WAN.
But the traffic is not being forwarded.
`net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` is out of comments.
`sudo sysctl -p` is executed.
ip route:

```
default via 192.168.224.2 dev ens9 proto dhcp metric 106

169.254.0.0/16 dev ens3 scope link metric 1000

192.168.1.0/30 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.2 metric 100

192.168.1.4/30 dev ens5 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.6 metric 102

192.168.1.8/30 dev ens7 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.10 metric 104

192.168.2.0/30 dev ens4 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.2 metric 101

192.168.2.4/30 dev ens6 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.6 metric 103

192.168.2.8/30 dev ens8 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.10 metric 105

192.168.224.0/24 dev ens9 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.224.138 metric 106
```

iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)

target     prot opt source               destination        

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)

target     prot opt source               destination    

ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)

target     prot opt source               destination
```

Following commands were used for iptables:

```
user@user-PC:~$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface ens3 -j ACCEPT

user@user-PC:~$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface ens5 -j ACCEPT

user@user-PC:~$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface ens7 -j ACCEPT

user@user-PC:~$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface ens4 -j ACCEPT

user@user-PC:~$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface ens6 -j ACCEPT

user@user-PC:~$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface ens8 -j ACCEPT

user@user-PC:~$ sudo iptables -t nat  -A POSTROUTING -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE

user@user-PC:~$ sudo iptables -t nat  -A POSTROUTING -o ens5 -j MASQUERADE

user@user-PC:~$ sudo iptables -t nat  -A POSTROUTING -o ens7 -j MASQUERADE

user@user-PC:~$ sudo iptables -t nat  -A POSTROUTING -o ens4 -j MASQUERADE

user@user-PC:~$ sudo iptables -t nat  -A POSTROUTING -o ens6 -j MASQUERADE

user@user-PC:~$ sudo iptables -t nat  -A POSTROUTING -o ens8 -j MASQUERADE
```

when testing the routing it seems ok:

```
user@user-PC:~$ ip route get 192.168.1.5 from 192.168.1.1 iif ens3

192.168.1.5 from 192.168.1.1 dev ens5

cache iif ens3

user@user-PC:~$ ip route get 192.168.1.1 from 192.168.1.5 iif ens5

192.168.1.1 from 192.168.1.5 dev ens3

cache iif ens5
```

any ideas would help me out a ton!
thx in advance

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I gave it a try, but I'm still unable to ping from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.6 or anywhere else

Comment: user@user-PC:~$ sysctl net.ipv4.conf.{all,ens3}.rp_filter
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 2
net.ipv4.conf.ens3.rp_filter = 2
user@user-PC:~$ sysctl net.ipv4.conf.{all,ens3,ens4,ens5,ens6,ens7,ens8}.rp_filter
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 2
net.ipv4.conf.ens3.rp_filter = 2
net.ipv4.conf.ens4.rp_filter = 2
net.ipv4.conf.ens5.rp_filter = 2
net.ipv4.conf.ens6.rp_filter = 2
net.ipv4.conf.ens7.rp_filter = 2
net.ipv4.conf.ens8.rp_filter = 2
net.ipv4.conf.ens8.rp_filter = 2

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
It was not a linux problem, it was a firewall problem, that did not have the correct routes.
Thanks for the help!